# Retrieve latest data from directory

Tags: perl

I want to retrieve number of lines from `data.list` in this directory : `Project/chris/company/Delta/force/run_20210619_df/total/data.list` But the problem is the `run_20210619_df` changes and is replaced everytime a new data is updated into data.list.

lets say original directory was :

`Project/chris/company/Delta/force/run_20210619_df/total/data.list`

but today the `data.list` is being updated, so a new directory is formed while the `run_20210619_df` still exist : `Project/chris/company/Delta/force/run_20210624_df/total/data.list`

and both the directory contains `data.list`

can i make a script that can always read **the LATEST version of** `data.list`? in this case its inside `run_20210624_df`

**I started with this :**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $files = './Project/chris/company/Delta/force/*/total/data.list';
my $hashref;

for my $file ( glob($files) ) {
    my($date) = (split('/',$_))[6];
    if( $hashref->{$id) and $date gt $hashref->{$id}{date} ) {
        $hashref->{$id}{file}   = $file;
        $hashref->{$id}{date}   = $date;
        $hashref->{$id}{count}  = count_lines($file);
    } else {
        $hashref->{$id}{file}   = $file;
        $hashref->{$id}{date}   = $date;
        $hashref->{$id}{count}  = count_lines($file);
    }
}

say Dumper($hashref);

sub count_lines {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $count;

    open my $fh, '<', $fname or die $!;
    $count++ while <$fh>;
    close $fh;

    return $count;
}
```

Unfortunately, when i run the script, it cant detect which data.list to pull info from. and thus prints 3 times as i have 3 different file of $date

Comment: If the varying part is just a timestamp in YYYYMMDD format, the newest file is always simply the last element in the `glob` result, isn't it?

Comment: Do you specifically want a solution written in `perl`?

Comment: @roaima yes must be in perl . or you know about other scripts type thats easier?

Comment: @DonHolgo hi, can u be more specific

Comment: @HelpMeAndroidStudio Can't you just use `my $file = glob($files)[-1]` instead of looping over all matched files?

Comment: im not sure, wdym

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the glob by each file's modification timestamp using the `stat` function.

e.g.

instead of:

```
for my $file ( glob($files) ) {
```

use:

```
for my $file ( sort { (stat $b)[9] <=> (stat $a)[9] } glob($files) ) {
```

This will sort in reverse timestamp order, i.e. the first element will be the newest.

You probably don't want to iterate over the entire list of files matching the glob, just use the most recent one:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $glob_pattern = './Project/chris/company/Delta/force/*/total/data.list';

my @files = ( sort { (stat $b)[9] <=> (stat $a)[9] } glob($glob_pattern) );
my $file = $files[0];

printf "%s: %i\n", $file, count_lines($file);

sub count_lines {
...
...
...
}
```

Why `(stat $b)[9]` and `(stat $a)[9]`?   Because the modification time is element number 9 of the 13 element list returned by the `stat` function.  It's commonly used like:

```
my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
    $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat($filename);
```

`atime`, `mtime`, are `ctime` are all numeric values, seconds since the epoch (Midnight, Jan 1, 1970 GMT) - i.e. standard unix time_t values.  Because they're numeric, they can be sorted, compared, added, subtracted, etc like any other numeric value.

See `perldoc -f stat` for more details on the stat function.

See also `perldoc -f sort` for details on the `sort` function.  In the code above, it uses a code block to sort by a value derived from the filename (i.e. their mtimes), rather than sorting by the filenames themselves.

BTW, remember that perl arrays start from 0, not 1.  So [9] is the tenth element, starting from zero.  Also, [6] is the seventh element, so your `(split('/',$_))[6]` should probably have been `[5]` instead of `[6]`.  Not needed now, since the code above uses the files' actual timestamps.

Comment: `sort {-M$a <=> -M$b}` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: perhaps.  I'm less concerned with "idiomatic" (and especially with "clever") than I am with teaching useful things and methods in as clear a manner as possible.   Using stat allowed me to teach something about both stat and sort in the one answer. Also, a very brief comment on why (stat $a)[9] "works", how an index or a slice can be applied to a returned list, not just to an array.

Comment: That's up to you, but I don't find `-M` more "clever". That's the perl operator to retrieve the age of a file. It feels more natural that retrieving the whole `stat()` structure and extract the mtime with hardcoded index. You can see it being used in `CPAN::CacheMgr` for instance.

Comment: Damned if I do, and damned if I don't.  On the one hand, I get whinged at if I use filetest operators that perl clearly and obviously copied from sh (like `-f` and `-e`) and on the other, I get berated by someone else for not using perl extensions of the same thing.   So I don't give a damn about other people's preferences, I just write my answers in the way that suits me.  Feel free to write your own perl-based answer using your own perl preferences.

Comment: @cas thanks for the excellent solution, one thing, if i want to display whats $count, normally i would use print `"$count";` , but in this case its not working, nothing is showing, any idea why?

Comment: $count is a lexically scoped variable that **only exists inside the count_files subroutine**.  If you try to use it outside of that sub, you will either get an empty string *or*, if `use strict` is in force, an error like `Global symbol "$count" requires explicit package name` (and you should always use strict).    Outside of `count_files()`, you can do something like `my $count = count_files($filename);` to create an entirely unrelated $count variable in that scope.  There's a good summary of this at [Scope of variables in Perl](https://perlmaven.com/scope-of-variables-in-perl)

Comment: @cas hi not  sure if there is any typo in ur answer , but when i use my `$count = count_lines($file);` it dosnt work

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a particularly useless way of not describing a problem.

Comment: nvm i got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
wc -l < ./Project/chris/company/Delta/force/run_<->_df/total/data.list([-1])
```

Would give the number of lines¹ in the `data.list` with the highest `run_..._df` number. While

```
wc -l < ./Project/chris/company/Delta/force/run_<->_df/total/data.list(-om[1])
```

Would give the number of lines in the most recently modified `data.list`.

Or to `O`rder `n`umerically on the first sequence of digits found in the paths:

```
wc -l < ./Project/chris/company/Delta/force/*/total/data.list(nOe['
  REPLY=${(MS)REPLY##<->}'][1])
```

---

<sup>¹ technically, of *newline characters*, which could give you a different number from the perl approach if the last "line" is not delimited.</sup>